# Настройка статусбара с плагином ALE

Tags: vim

Хочу сделать отображение строки в которой находится первая ошибка. На гитхабе ALE есть упоминание про `ale#statusline#FirstProblem`, в `:h` тоже написано. Сделал так, как мне кажется оно должно работать, но при проверке файла оно отваливается, ругается на то, что `printf()` получает слишком много аргументов.

```
function! LinterStatus() abort
    let l:counts = ale#statusline#Count(bufnr(''))
    let l:first = ale#statusline#FirstProblem(bufnr(''), 'error')

    let l:all_errors = l:counts.error + l:counts.style_error
    let l:all_non_errors = l:counts.total - l:all_errors

    return l:counts.total == 0 ? 'OK ' : printf(
    \   '%dW %dE ',
    \   all_non_errors,
    \   all_errors,
    \   first
    \)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрев через несколько часов внимательнее, я понял, что я <del>дурень</del> был невнимателен.
В `prinf()` передавалось два агрумента и три значения для них.

Рабочий вариант:

```
function! LinterStatus() abort
    let l:counts = ale#statusline#Count(bufnr(''))
    let l:first = ale#statusline#FirstProblem(bufnr(''), 'error')

    let l:all_errors = l:counts.error + l:counts.style_error
    let l:all_non_errors = l:counts.total - l:all_errors

    return l:counts.total == 0 ? 'OK ' : printf(
    \   '%dW %dE(L%s)',
    \   all_non_errors,
    \   all_errors,
    \   first.lnum
    \)
endfunction
```

[image: Как это выглядит]